# Django SQL setting up a default schema to all the tables

Tags: python, sql, django, reactjs

I am setting up a local environment for a project which is built with DJANGO+React and SQL Server

I had my SQL connection set up like this

```
DATABASES={
'default': {
        'ENGINE':'sql_server.pyodbc',
        'NAME':'Test_Db',
        'USER':'Test_User',
        'PASSWORD':'************',
        'HOST':'*******',
        'PORT':'****',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'dsn':'FreeTDS',
            'autocommit':True,
    }
}
```

}

I was able to connect to database but for some reason there were new tables created back in database with new schema dbo and all the tables are empty.

[image]

But I have all the user data in different schema app. where I need to connect and perform all the operations.

[image]
When I am running the local server it's referencing it to DBO where I don't have any data which resulting login errors.

Is there any way I can set in manage.py or setting.py to consider app schema for all the models defined.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the search_path in your DATABASES, in settings.py.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'options': '-c search_path=first_schema,second_schema,third_schema'
        },
        'NAME': '',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    },
}
```

Add your desired schema to be in the first place.